# Can I use the parent selector for multi-classed elements?

Tags: css, sass

I'm converting some css files to Sass. The [documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#referencing_parent_selectors_) is a little unclear about one thing though, can I use the `&` parent reference like this:

**.css**

```
.class {
  background:red;
}

.class.otherclass{
  background:green;
}
```

**.scss**

```
.class {
  background:red;

  &.otherclass{
    background:green;
  }
}
```

Comment: @cimmanon Which space?

Comment: The comment I was replying to was removed, they assumed you meant `.class .otherClass` instead of `.class.otherClass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can

[Here's the relevant documentation](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand).